# <secure-deployment name="business-central.war"> ^^^^ 'secure-deployment' isn't an allowed element here

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, jbpm, redhat-bpm

Good morning I am trying to perform an SSO integration (keycloak) with RHPam (JBPM) but when configuring the adapter in JBoss (Wildfly) it throws the following error:

```html
22:02:24,920 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.8.Final-redhat-00001
22:02:26,095 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)

OPVDX001: Validation error in standalone.xml -----------------------------------
|
|  585:     </outbound-socket-binding>
|  586: </socket-binding-group>
|  587:  <secure-deployment name="business-central.war">
|        ^^^^ 'secure-deployment' isn't an allowed element here
|
|             Elements allowed here are:
|               deployment-overlays   management            system-properties
|               deployments           paths                 vault
|               extensions            profile
|               interfaces            socket-binding-group
|
|  588:     <realm>Amer</realm>
|  589:     <auth-server-url>http://($url-Server)/auth/</auth-server-url>
|  590:     <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
|
| The primary underlying error message was:
| > ParseError at [row,col]:[587,6]
| > Message: WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element
| >   '{urn:jboss:domain:11.0}secure-deployment' encountered
|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

22:02:26,111 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.Confi
gurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:383)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The settings used are the following:

```html
  <secure-deployment name="kie-server.war">
        <realm>Sykes</realm>
        <auth-server-url>http://($urlServer)/auth/</auth-server-url>
        <public-client>true</public-client>
        <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
        <resource>kie-execution-server</resource>
        <verify-token-audience>true</verify-token-audience>
        <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
    </secure-deployment>
```

someone has an idea what it can be

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the problem is not the contents of your `secure-deployment` configuration, but its placement. It should likely be put under keycloak subsystem element.

Comment: I don't understand what the solution